# Downloading 40,000+ row csv with Django fails with "Network error"

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a paginated table that consumes data from an endpoint that returns JSON with Django ReST Framework (DRF). Table filtering is achieved through passing URL parameters to DRF. I'm building a button that let's the user download the filtered data as a CSV. The button works with around 10K rows, but failing when the number of results is above 20K.

The download is saying `Failed - Network error`, but I can see in the network tab of Chrome dev tools that the request I made for the csv data is succeeding with a 200 response code. Here is the function that returns the CSV response:

```
def download_csv(data):

    pseudo_buffer = Echo()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(pseudo_buffer, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    rows_to_write = [
        {'col1': 'a', 'col2': 'b', 'col3': 'c'},
        {'col1': 'e', 'col2': 'f', 'col3': 'g'},
        # 40K more rows here that are calculated
        # from the data parameter which is
        # serializer.data (a DRF serializer)
    ]

    # setup streaming http response
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(
        (writer.writerow(row) for row in rows_to_write),
        content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="download.csv"'

    return response
```

I started by trying to use Django's `HttpResponse`. This was working for 10K rows, but was failing with 20K+ rows. I switched to `StreamingHttpResponse` as described in [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files) from the Django documentation, hoping that this would allow me to download CSV files with larger amounts of rows. I'm stuck with the same limits as I had when using `HttpResponse`.

Here is the Javascript function I'm using to download the CSV file:

```
downloadCsv(){
  apiCall.get(
    `/api/download-csv/${this.$route.params.id}`,
    { params: { ...this.params, limit: this.count, offset: 0, excel: true }}
  ).then((resp)=>{
      const element = document.createElement('a');
      element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(resp.data));
      element.setAttribute('download', "download.csv");
      element.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(element);
      element.click();
      document.body.removeChild(element);
    }
  )
},
```

It is working just fine for smaller numbers of rows, but is failing for larger number of rows.

Comment: I don't think its an issue with Django. Maybe its related to NGINX/Apache or whatever proxy server you are using?

Comment: @ruddra OK, I am using nginx and gunicorn. Could it be that I need to adjust `keep_alive` settings?

Comment: I am not sure(not an expert in Nginx), but you can try that(also try to increase the timeout)

Comment: [django-queryset-csv](https://pypi.org/project/django-queryset-csv/) use this package.